# Alternative solutions for android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 

Tags: java, android, exception

Now I'm solving the

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I put the connect method into separated thread, but when the thread starts, the `start()` method doesn't invoke the `Run()`,
- and also using the `AsyncTask`, the task doesn't invoke the `doInBackground()` method!

---

### // For The AsyncTask  my code was

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, HttpEntity> {

    HttpEntity entity;
    String  statue;
    LogInJSONActivity mainActivity;
    @Override
    protected HttpEntity doInBackground(URL... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mainActivity.setString("Inside Do in background");
         entity = connect(arg0[0]);
         mainActivity.setHttp(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public  HttpEntity connect(String url) {

        statue= "Inside Connect";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            entity = response.getEntity();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return entity;
    }
    public void setActivity(LogInJSONActivity act){
        mainActivity = act;
    }
}
```

### -> In The Main Activity

```
URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.flickr.com/photos/51469488@N03/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ConnectTask backgroundTask = (ConnectTask) new ConnectTask();
        backgroundTask.setActivity(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(url);
```

---

### // For The Thread My code Was :-

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    HttpEntity entity;
    String  statue;
    LogInJSONActivity mainActivity;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mainActivity.setString("Inside Run");
         entity = connect("http://www.flickr.com/photos/51469488@N03/");
         mainActivity.setHttp(entity);
         super.run();   
    }

    public  HttpEntity connect(String url) {

        statue= "Inside Connect";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            entity = response.getEntity();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(entity !=null)
            System.out.print("Valid Entity");
        else
            System.out.print("Null Entity");


        return entity;
    }
    public void setActivity(LogInJSONActivity act){
        mainActivity = act;
    }      
}
```

---

### -> In the MainActivity

```
ConnectThread t = new ConnectThread();
        t.setActivity(this);
        t.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `error` is probably because you are doing some `Network` Operation on your `UI` `thread`, which is not allowed from `API 11`.I would say not to create a seperate `Thread`, just use `AsyncTask` class to execute your `Network` `operation`. Just do your Network Operation in `doInBackground()` and call the AsyncTask class from the UI thread as,

```
new YourAsyncTask().execute(url);
```

Thats all no need to put much efforts by creating a seperate `Thread` class and making it more complicated.

Comment: Thanks "Lalit Poptani" for your reply, But Actually I did What you say, and the execute function doesn't invoke the "doInBackGround()" method.